# apache commons ftpsclient hang on disconnect after login failure

Tags: java, windows, ftp-client

I am using apache commons library version 3.3 for FTPS transfer in a java application. The issue I face is, when the login function fails and the disconnect function is called, it hangs over there and does not come back.

I have tried setting the following timeout functions, but those did not work:

```
setDefaultTimeout()
setSoTimeout()
setDataTimeout() 
setConnectTimeout()
```

Can anybody suggest me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After some study figured out that it is not possible to guarantee non-blocking i/o call using apache commons api, since commons uses i/o api internally. Instead of using I/O api's need to use nio (non-blocking) api's. That way we can avoid blocking i/o calls.